How do I create a mathematical exact expression for linear dynamic velocity that changes according to varying distance from arc?
I have a linear running line which can move at varying speeds as part of an infinite axis, above an arc (part of a circle, of radius 'R') with width 'D'.
The minimal distance between the arc and the infinite axis is 't'.
From the line (and running with it), a beam of radiation of width 'l' with constant power 'P' is shot downwards and hits the arc (at different locations each moment).
I'm trying to figure out the velocity profile, that is V(x) (X is the horizontal axis in this example) which will end in the arc experiencing the exact amount of energy in each of its segments.
The following image shows the theoretical system:

I can't seem to understand How to begin my calculation (I'm looking for an integral of some sort or maybe a differential equation). Can someone help me understand how to begin?

what is the equation of the energy in your case ? E=?

The energy is spread evenly (both in respect to time and to position). If you wish, then d^2E/dtdx = const.
